# Checking selectedIndex doesn't match when selecting multiple options in select element

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="s1" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="stype"
          onchange="showfield1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" required>
        <option>Diamond</option>
        <option>Ruby</option>
        <option>Sapphire</option>
        <option>Emerald</option>
        <option>Tanzanite</option>
        <option>Pink Sapphire</option>
        <option>Aqua</option>
        <option>Blue Topaz</option>
        <option>Amethyst</option>
        <option>Pearl</option>
        <option>Garnet</option>
        <option>Citrine</option>
        <option>Opal</option>
        <option>Other</option>
      </select>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function showfield1(name) {
          if (name == 'Other') document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML =
              '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="stypeother"'
              + ' placeholder="Please Specify"/>';
          else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '';
        }
      </script>
      <div id="div1"></div>
```

With the above code, if I select any other `<option>` in addition to `Other` then the `Please Specify` `<input>` is not displayed. That `<input>` is visible only when the only selected `<option>` is `Other`. I want the `Please Specify` `<input>` to be displayed anytime the `Other` `<option>` is selected, regardless of any other `<option>` also being selected.

I am using the the `selectedIndex` of the `<select>` to obtain the `value` of the selected `<option>` and testing to see if that `value` is equal to `Other`. But, that is not working. How do I determine if the `Other` `<option>` is selected?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: well that's what the code shown should do as it is written. We don't know what your expectations are. Please review [ask]

Comment: I want the div tag to be visible if "Other" is selected, the above code works only when "Other" is the only option that is selected, whenever I select more options with "Other" the div tag becomes invisible

Comment: you are not clear....please be specific...because what you want is happening in this code....

Comment: do you want to select "Other" and then make visible the Div..and if we select other options then "Other" then the Div should not disappears ??

Comment: @user3691204, I have significantly edited your question to make what I believe to be your actual question more clear. Feel free to revert it or [edit] it further if I was mistaken in my understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check to see if the `Other` `<option>` is selected.  The [`selectedIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex) will only return the index of the first selected `<option>`. Given that `Other` is your last `<option>`, `selectedIndex` will never be the index for `Other` when anything else is selected. One way to check if `Other` is selected is to give the `Other` `<option>` an `id` and then check the `selected` property of the `Other` `<option>`.

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="s1" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="stype"
          onchange="showfield1()" required>
        <option>Diamond</option>
        <option>Ruby</option>
        <option>Sapphire</option>
        <option>Emerald</option>
        <option>Tanzanite</option>
        <option>Pink Sapphire</option>
        <option>Aqua</option>
        <option>Blue Topaz</option>
        <option>Amethyst</option>
        <option>Pearl</option>
        <option>Garnet</option>
        <option>Citrine</option>
        <option>Opal</option>
        <option id="optionOther">Other</option>
      </select>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function showfield1() {
          if (document.getElementById('optionOther').selected) {
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '<input type="text"'
                + ' class="form-control" name="stypeother"'
                + ' placeholder="Please Specify"/>';
          } else {
            document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = '';
          }
        }
      </script>
      <div id="div1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`selectedOptions`** property of *Multiple-Select-Element* in Javascript.

See below code and replace it with your JavaScript code.

```
function showfield1(){
s1 = document.getElementById('s1');
var found = 0;
for ( var i = 0; i < s1.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
    if(s1.selectedOptions[i].value=='Other')
      found =1;

}

if(found)document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input type="text" class="form-control" name="stypeother" placeholder="Please Specify"/>';
else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
```

below is full Fiddle..check this

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <select id="s1" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="stype" onchange="showfield1()" required>
        <option>Diamond</option>
        <option>Ruby</option>
        <option>Sapphire</option>
        <option>Emerald</option>
        <option>Tanzanite</option>
        <option>Pink Sapphire</option>
        <option>Aqua</option>
        <option>Blue Topaz</option>
        <option>Amethyst</option>
        <option>Pearl</option>
        <option>Garnet</option>
        <option>Citrine</option>
        <option>Opal</option>
        <option>Other</option>
      </select>

      <script type="text/javascript">
        function showfield1(){
        s1 = document.getElementById('s1');
        var found = 0;
        for ( var i = 0; i < s1.selectedOptions.length; i++) {
           if(s1.selectedOptions[i].value=='Other')
           found =1;
        }

        if(found)document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='<input type="text" class="form-control" name="stypeother" placeholder="Please Specify"/>';
        else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
        }
      </script>
      <div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: and remove `onchange="showfield1(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)` line because there is no use of this code here in your code.

Comment: just write your code as `<select id="s1" multiple="multiple" class="form-control" name="stype" onchange="showfield1()" required>`

Comment: In an ideal world, using `selectedOptions` would be a good option for implementing this. Unfortunately, it is [not supported in Internet Explorer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement#Browser_compatibility).  In IE (e.g. IE11), this results in throwing an error. Specifically, `"Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference"`

Comment: WRT: Your comment below: You present this answer as a general solution when it **throws an error in >20% of browsers currently in use**. The OP did not state they were looking for a solution which did not include working in IE. Importantly, you have made *no mention in the answer regarding this limitation (throws error in IE)*. In 5-10 years when compatibility with IE<=11 is not much of a concern, then using `selectedOptions` may be the correct choice. So, yes I did down vote because, *right now, and for years to come, it is not a good solution for code which is used for general distribution.*